# Using an UltraSharp 27 4K USB-C Monitor: U2720Q display with a Insprion 5579

Tags: external-display, dell-inspiron, usb-c

Can I simply plug the USB-C cable of a UltraSharp 27 4K USB-C Monitor: U2720Q into a Insprion 5579 USB 3.0 Type A port with and adapter and use all of the display features except PD? Or alternatively Just use the connected USB Devices and connect video over HDMI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot. USB-C DisplayPort Alt Mode *output* is only possible with USB-C. You indicate you have a type A connector. Of course, a USB-C port still has to support it. The port being USB-C is not enough.

USB should work though, since the monitor has no other USB upstream port.

Answer (score 0):

For passing display through USB you need USB Alternate Mode.

This is defined by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C#Alternate_Mode)
as:

> An Alternate Mode dedicates some of the physical wires in a **USB-C 3.1** cable for direct device-to-host transmission of alternate data protocols.

The answer is negative : You need USB-C 3.1 on both ends, but you don't have it
on even one of the two.